# SQLAlchemy "Exception during reset or similar" + "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm getting an error when running this code:

```
engine = sa.create_engine([connection_str])
connection = engine.connect()
```

Partial traceback:

```
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 682, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 887, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 667, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1236, in rollback
    self._execute_query("ROLLBACK")
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1248, in _execute_query
    self.cmd_query(query)
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 828, in cmd_query
    packet.extend(lc_int(len(self._query_attrs)))
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/utils.py", line 164, in lc_int
    return bytearray(struct.pack('<B', i))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
Exception closing connection <mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7fc69049fee0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 682, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 887, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 667, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1236, in rollback
    self._execute_query("ROLLBACK")
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1248, in _execute_query
    self.cmd_query(query)
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 828, in cmd_query
    packet.extend(lc_int(len(self._query_attrs)))
  File "/Users/philipjoss/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/utils.py", line 164, in lc_int
    return bytearray(struct.pack('<B', i))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

[Full traceback](https://pastebin.pl/view/76d8fb63)

Queries etc work fine if I add a session but I always get this error at the end of the code running.

Python is 3.9.6, SQLAlchemy is 1.4.23, MySQL is 8.0.26.

Any ideas?

---

**Update:**

I've upgraded to SQLAlchemy 1.4.25 but still getting the error...

Comment: Can you share the connection string?

Comment: `"mysql+mysqlconnector://root:examplepassword@localhost/"`

Comment: Is that traceback displayed even if you do not run any query?

Comment: @Cheche - yep :-(

Comment: If you can't post the complete traceback in the question, can you post it on pastebin or similar?

Comment: How, _exactly_, does your program terminate?  The only similar case I can find is [this](https://groups.google.com/g/pymysql-users/c/I_rIUnYoEck).  Can you reproduce the problem using only MySQL Connector (SQLA is just calling the DBAPI connection's rollback method).

Comment: @snakecharmerb - added full traceback to my question. Thanks for the pointer to the google group - adding `connection.close()` got rid of the error. I'm not sure what you mean by only using the MySQL Connector - I assumed this meant using the following connection string - `"mysqlconnector://root:examplepassword@localhost/"` - this resulted in the following error - `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysqlconnector`

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems similar to [this](https://groups.google.com/g/pymysql-users/c/I_rIUnYoEck) report for a pymysql issue: when Python shuts down, it isn't always possible to rely on modules still being present in `sys.modules`, and so a module that was apparently successfully imported (`struct`) is now `None`, resulting in the `AttributeError`.

The workaround proposed in the Google Groups thread - explicitly closing the connection - works for the asker of this question.

In SQLAlchemy we could also use the connection as a context manager to close it automatically:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
   # Do stuff
# Connection is closed when we leave the `with` block
```

Even though the above works, it leaves some open questions:

- the Google Groups thread suggests this behaviour was fixed in Python 3.4, so it isn't clear why it happens in Python 3.9
- the issue was reported for PyMySQL, not MySQL Connector (perhaps not so surprising if the bug is in Python core, or if both libraries finalize connections in the same way)
- the issue is not reproducible (at least not for me, on Linux)

In theory it should be possible to reproduce the issue with SQLAlchemy, for example something like

```py
import mysql.connector as mc

conn = mc.connect(*connect_args)

# Do stuff?

conn.rollback()
```

However I could not reproduce the behaviour this way either.

Answer (score -1):

Do ensure the *syntax is correct* along with the correct case( case sensitive)

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:examplepassword@localhost/")
    connection = engine.connect()
```

Check this [documentation link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html) and [dialect doc link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html) for guidance

> The MySQL dialect uses mysql-python as the default DBAPI. There are many MySQL DBAPIs available, including MySQL-connector-python and OurSQL:
>
> ###### default
>
> `engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')`
>
> ###### mysqlclient (a maintained fork of MySQL-Python)
>
> `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')`
>
> ###### PyMySQL
>
> `engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')`